# Why doesn't my remove() actually remove reference from DB using JPA @Many-to-Many

Tags: jpa, many-to-many

I have a pretty simple JPA `@ManyToMany` relationship set up in my application.  A `Product` is a part of one or more `OrderSystem`s.  Each `OrderSystem` can have many `Product`s.  It's a typical many-to-many relationship.

The problem I'm fighting with is this: If I use `orderSystems.remove()` to remove a reference from a `Product` to an `OrderSystem`, the entry appears to be removed (within that session).  However, the entry isn't removed from the cross-reference table on flush, and when I reload the `Product` it has the previous set of `OrderSystem`s.

I have the following code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "p_product_versions")
@Validation
public class Product {
    private List<OrderSystem> orderSystems;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "p_order_systems_has_product_versions", 
            joinColumns =
                @JoinColumn(name = "p_product_versions_prod_version_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns =
                @JoinColumn(name = "p_order_systems_system_id"))
    public List<OrderSystem> getOrderSystems() {
        return orderSystems;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "p_order_systems")
@Validation
public class OrderSystem {
    private List<Product> products;
    @ManyToMany (mappedBy = "orderSystems")
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me at what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that the problem was that I was not clearing the relationship in both directions.  I would remove a Product from the OrderSystem but not remove the OrderSystem from the Product.

Answer (score 2):

What does the code where you do the remove look like?  Are you doing it in a transaction, and are you remembering to commit your changes?

Comment: Yes to both -- I have figured out what I was doing wrong, and will submit my own answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove relationship from both sides.
The way to do it is:

```
// Find your 2 beans with entityManager

product.setOrderSystems(null);
orderSystem.setProducts(null);

// then persist() and flush()
```

Comment: this is not a real answer. Please, delete it and post as as comment instead. Also, I'd like to ask you to take a few minutes to read the FAQ - http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: Hi jweyrich ! I've changed my previous post by a code solution. Now this question has a real interest ;-)